# how to keep flutter app run in background?

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, background

Hi I want create app with flutter for android and I have some problem. I want my app work in background and even when close. and my app has some text for report that change in so everyday on specific time or in period of time for example each 10 min.
I want even when my app in background or is close the app keep working and show the notification to user.
how to do this? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flutter_background_service from pub.dev or simply follow this article
[Background Service for Flutter](https://medium.com/dlt-labs-publication/flutter-run-code-in-the-background-461b4d6c635b)

Answer (score 0):

use package [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) for running code in background